# Load Runner generates NetAccessorException even though web_submit_data returns as expected

Tags: loadrunner

I get the following error on about 15 of my 50,000 requests during my hour test.  Is this a network issue or is Load Runner 11 generating the error?

InquiryRequest.c(170): Error: An exception occurred! Type:NetAccessorException, Message:The host/address 'www.server.com' could not be resolved (line 2, col 102)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the nature of the error this appears to be a DNS related issue in name resolution.   If you want to avoid this issue altogether simply replace your hostname, "www.server.com," with the IP address for the host and your application under test.   This will remove any dependency on name resolution either from a DNS server or from a local hosts file.

Comment: I actually opted for the hosts file route which solved the problem.  Having it in the script is a far better route because I never need to update the load generators with an updated hosts file.